# Tool to capture mp3 stream on a schedule

Tags: mp3, streaming

I'm looking for a tool that will:

- capture a stream from an internet radio station (an MP3 stream)
- save it as an MP3 file
- allow me schedule a capture in the future

It could be desktop or cloud based.

Comment: Desktop-what? I guess Windows (as not explicitely named) – but you could also mean Mac or Linux :)

Comment: Preferably on Windows, but Linux would be good too.

Comment: OK then, for Linux take a look at [Streamripper](http://streamripper.sourceforge.net/) then. I have not used it myself, but heard it praised a couple of times. See also its [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streamripper) for some more details. As it claims to be cross-platform, it might even work on Windows.